# How to switch to virtual terminal when there is no GUI installed on a Linux server?

Tags: terminal, tty, console

I'm trying to understand terminal, console, tty, virtual terminal, terminal emulator and this kind of things. Below is the topology of my environment. There is a Linux server and a Windows 10 PC. I use `putty` on the PC and connect to the Linux server. In this case, it seems <kbd>ctrl + alt + f1~6</kbd> can't bring me to other virtual terminals. I know if the Linux server has GUI installed, I can press <kbd>ctrl + alt + f1~6</kbd> when I'm directly connected to the server (for example, I have a keyboard and monitor plugged in it). My question is:

- Can I use multiple virtual terminals in my topology?
- If the Linux server has GUI installed (like Gnome), can I use multiple virtual terminals in the same topology (connect through SSH)?
- In this topology, is `putty` a terminal? A console? Or a terminal emulator?

I've actually read several articles and related sections in different books. It seems different people introduce these concepts a little bit different and I'm still confused. IMO, this is the hardest part of my Linux learning journey.

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
|                     |
|     Linux Server    |
| (No GUI installed)  |
|                     |
+-----------+---------+
            ^
            |
            | SSH
            |
 +----------+--------+
 |          |        |
 |      +---+---+    |
 |      | Putty |    |
 |      +-------+    |
 |                   |
 |    Windows 10 PC  |
 |                   |
 +-------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every computer running linux (server noGui, laptops with Gui... etc) does have tty (if you plug a keyboard and use ctrl+alt+fX you will see).

When you uses putty for ssh you use a ssh client (like openssh-client on linux and other unix-like systems).

When you connect to a server using ssh, you are connecting remotely and the ssh server provides to your client a command line interface.

Viewed by the server when you are connected, by ssh you are not on a tty `/dev/ttyX` but pty `/dev/pts/X`

Then if you want to switch to another command line interface on a server, you just have to start a new ssh connection or if you have screen or tmux installed on the server, you can split the current command line interface in two terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tty`-command to see which terminal you are currently. If you'll give it a try, you'll see that all terminal emulators and ssh-accesses lead to e.g. `/dev/pts/X` while when "directly" accessing the machine (i.e. monitor+keyboard plugged in) you will get `/dev/ttyX`. (Side note: instead of using <kbd>CRTL+ALT+FX</kbd>, `chvt X` will work in the latter case, too)

`pts` means pseudo-terminal and I do not know of any way to change it from the terminal itself - however it shows us that your `ssh`-session (i.e. `putty`) is in fact behaving the same way as a terminal emulator. (a bit more on this topic to be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/123460))

Your options are thus:

- multiple `putty`-sessions that you can thus switch with <kbd>ALT+TAB</kbd> from Windows
- a terminal multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux` that can start multiple pseudo-terminals ans switch between them (and even split your screen to have two or more terminals in one view)

In the GUI-case you are limited in the same way as with the CLI-case.